# Extracting text from URL using $_GET gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, get

I'm trying to extract an id from **get-albums-genres.php?gid=".$id."** using $_GET and it gives me undefined!

I fetched data for music genres in an **array** after running an **SQL** query to extract data from my **genre table**

```
$dbcursor = $db->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM GENRES_TBL
    ORDER BY ID
    ");

$genres = [];
while($takegenre = $dbcursor->fetch_object()) $genres[] = $takegenre;
```

After this I created a **html table** containing **<a tags** with hyperlinks for each genre using foreach loop.

```
    <?php
    foreach($genres as $gs)
    {
        $id = $gs->ID;
        echo "
            <a class='gentons' href='get-albums-genres.php?gid=".$id."'>".$gs->GENRE."</a>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

With these hyperlinks I want to show table of all albums from selected genre. In order to do that i plan to extract the id from the **href** and than use it in an SQL query to connect the albums genre id to the genres ids, BUT in the **php file** for getting the albums when declaring the variable and using $_GET to extract the id it gives me undefined value.

```
$genre_id = $_GET['gid'];

echo"$genre_id";   //undefined

if(isset ($_GET['gid'])){
    echo"yes";
}else{
    echo"no";
}  //yes
```

The Javascript code with the event is

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a.gentons', function(e)
            {
            $.get('get-albums-genres.php?gid=' + $('input[name="gid"]').val(),
            function(data)
                {
                $('#albums-list').html(data);
                });
            return false;
            })
```

It's strange because i did exactly the same in another php file where i input **name or best-song** of an artist and find and show all his albums and i have no problems with the $_GET method there. I also don't understand why when i **hover my cursor over the hyperlinks** for the genres it show the link and the corresponding id, but when i try to extract it there is a problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YJf3.png)

Comment: PHP only should work fine. The problem may come from your JS because I don't see any `<input name="gid">`. So, it will becomes `undefined`.

Comment: If you code **only** `$genre_id = $_GET['gid'];` while the URL have no `?gid=xx` you will get error message _Warning: Undefined array key "gid"_. It is not just `undefined`. That `undefined` is come from JavaScript part.

Comment: The jQuery `$.get()` is function that make AJAX request to destination (**get-albums-genres.php?gid=xxx**) and you modify the `?gid=` value with `$('input[name="gid"]').val()` while there is **no** `<input name="gid">` anywhere as I said. So, I hope you can fix your problem now.

Comment: Why not: `$.get( $(this).attr('href'), function(data) { ... })`

Comment: There is nothing in PHP that would replace a value with the word "undefined". Javascript, on the other hand, has a null type that stringifies as "undefined". Your problem is definitely not in PHP, and most likely in your javascript.

Comment: Thank you guys, all of your comments were very useful! I suspected that the problem lies in the rooting of the url entities between the js file and the php file, but i couldn't think of and find a way to connect them and also the attr() method made everything much better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems here. First, instead of using the href in your link tag (you never want anyone to actually visit that URL, right?), let's set the href to `#` and put our genre ID in a data attribute. Let's get our single/double quotes straight while we're at it.

```php
echo '<a class="gentons" data-gid="' . $id . '" href="#">' . $gs->GENRE . '</a>';
```

Now in our JS, we can cancel the event with `preventDefault()`, grab the genre ID, and everything else stays the same.

```javascript
$(document).on('click', 'a.gentons', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.get('get-albums-genres.php?gid=' + $(this).data('gid'),
        function (data)
        {
            $('#albums-list').html(data);
        });
    
    return false;
});
```

This should work, or at least get you to your next bug.

Comment: Thank you, i did understand the ideas and the data attribute and believe it will be very useful in the future!